Inconsistent DataFrame Search Results Using LangChain AI Agent
I'm working on a project using a LangChain AI agent to read and query pandas DataFrames. The agent receives detailed instructions in the pre-prompt, including chat history and metadata for the tables. However, I am experiencing troubles with how it reads string inputs from the user and translates it to pandas queries.
The Langchain agent is designed to answer questions about the data set but also create graphical representations using plotly. All of this is explained in detailed in the pre-prompt and for the most part it works very well.
However, every now and then I will write something, and it will not interpret it correctly. When searching for data about a country, I sometimes receive inconsistent results. For instance, Puerto Rico is typically identified by the code "PRI," but occasionally the agent searches for "PR," which returns no rows. For Mexico, if the user says Mexico or MEX, the agent will grab the results as those are both seen in the data frame under two separate columns (country code and country). However, if a random user decided to use 'MX' for Mexico, sometimes the agent will query the df with MX and it will return an empty set and no visualization or answer for the user.
This can also sometimes occur when country names are capitalized vs when they are not in the user's questions. However, I have included a line in the pre prompt to take care of this.
I have included metadata for every column in 3 different data sets and added it to the pre-prompt. The agent also has access to chat_history with memory. I don't want to consistently add a specific case for each country or minor detail when it comes to the way users ask questions about different items in the data set. I have set the temperature for the AI to be 0 by the way.
What can I do to fix this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please check How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example Stack Overflow guidelines.
